# related field through lookup

Tags: apex, visualforce, relationships, childrelationship

I have a custom object with a lookup field to the standard object Contact. If I use the custom object as a standard controller how do I acces the salutation and lastname on the contact object. I tried:

> - {!Contact.Salutation}
> - {!Contacts.Salutation}
> - {!Contact__r.Salutation}
> - {!CustomObject.Contact__r.Salutation}

None of these seem to work
How do I find the relationship name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last attempt was the closest; you need to specify the full custom object name (which includes "__c"):

```
{!CustomObject__c.Contact__r.Salutation}
```

Comment: I tried the __c on the custom object but that didn't work eighter. Could this be becouse of a manage package?My field record looks like: Edit Managed - Installed 
Contact
soco__Contact__c StepOrange | Converse Lookup(Contact) Checked

Comment: @Jenssen, check the relationship API name in workbench and use that

Comment: @Jenssen if it's managed, you also need to include namespaces, if applicable, e.g. `{!ns__Obj__c.ns__Contact__r.Salutation}`

Comment: @Santanu I have {!soco__Memberships__c.Contacts__r.Salutation}    Workbench says:Contact.Membership__c
cascadeDelete: false
childSObject: Contact
deprecatedAndHidden: false
field: Membership__c
relationshipName: Contacts__r

Comment: @Jenssen It looks like memberships is a *parent* to contacts, not a child.

Comment: @sfdcfox if I make contact my standard controller I can save the visualforce page with {!Contact.soco__Memberships__r[0].Kaart__c} but i get the error on preview: ExecutionException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: soco__Membership__c.Kaart__c . So do i need to make a controller extension to retrieve the fields?

Comment: @Jenssen No, you shouldn't need an extension for this. However, you do need to make sure you've got the correct API name, including namespace prefix. I think you're getting yourself confused about the relationship you're trying to use. You need to look at the membership object to discover the contact field's API name.